# Rails Routing and View Helper Names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have this route defined in my routes.rb:

```
matc "articles/:id/vote/up" => "articles#vote", :liked=>true
```

The rake for this route is:

```
/articles/:id/vote/up(.:format) jokes#vote {:liked=>true}
```

With the first column being blank.
My question is, what would the route helper name be for this link?
For example articles_vote_up_path(:id).
Is there an uglier way to link to this path?
How can I find out?

I'm thinking I misunderstood something, please guide me in the correct direction in that case.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass an `:as` option to use a named route

`match "articles/:id/vote/up" => "articles#vote", :liked=>true, as: :article_vote_up`

which generates an `article_vote_up_path`

Answer (score 0):

When you run `rake routes`, you can add `_path` to the whatever's in the first column on the left, and that's what the route url helper is for that link. For example, here's a line from `rake routes` on one of my projects:

```
              subscriptions GET  /subscriptions(.:format) subscriptions#index
```

The url helper for this url would be `subscriptions_path`.

Comment: The problem is, the first column is blank (in this case). Is there a reason for this?

Comment: As @jvnill properly identified (and I overlooked), if you use `match`, it will only generate a url helper if you're using a "standard-ish" route. I'm not actually sure what the criteria are for this. (Here are some URLs from one of my rails applications that do and do not have autogenerated URLs when using match: `departments     /v1/schedule/:semester:year/departments(.:format)                                           departments#index` `/v1/schedule/:semester:year/departments/:department_number(.:format)                        departments#show` )